# Zero considered as empty in PHP

Tags: php, forms, input, is-empty

I've got a problem with an *input field* in my php form. It looks like:

```
<input type="number" name="tmax" max="99" min="-99" placeholder="Temperatura max.">
```

I want to check whether the *field* is empty or not. But the problem is php considers `0` as empty.

```
if (empty($_POST['tmax'])) {
  $tmax = null;
}else {
  $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

If the user leaves the *input field* empty the value is considered as 'null', which works perfectly. But if the user writes `0`, which is a possibility in the form, it is also treated as empty.

I've also set the default as null in SQL but the problem is, if the input is empty, the program inserts `0` in the table.

**SOLUTION:**

This solution works fine for me:

```
if ($_POST['tmax'] == "") {
  $tmax = null;
}else {
  $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

And also with `is_numeric()`

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['tmax'])) {
  $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}else {      
    $tmax = 'null';
}
```

Comment: Try to create a custom statement when the degree is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use

```
if ($_POST['tmax'] == "") {
  $tmax = null;
}else {
  $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

Comment: This will throw notices.

Comment: See lucianov's better answer, which includes `!isset` to avoid the php warning chris mentions. Or any other answer below (except Lesiuk's, which is quite good for a different situation, but not what is asked for here).

Answer (score 4):

Check if the condition is empty, and also not zero. A zero-value is "empty", so by adding both checks, you ensure that the variable `$tmax` will be set to `null` if the input was empty **and** not zero.

```
if (empty($_POST['tmax']) && $_POST['tmax'] != 0) {
    $tmax = null;
} else {
    $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

This will also accept "foo" as a value, so you should check or validate that the input is a valid number (and also in the ranges you specified). You can also implement `is_numeric($_POST['tmax'])`, or even better, validate it with `filter_var($_POST['tmax'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` to ensure that whatever was input is actually a number.

- [PHP.net on `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
- [PHP.net on `is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)
- [PHP.net on `filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)
- [PHP.net on flags for usage in `filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: IMHO, its a confusing technique to use `empty`, then add additional tests to correct for `empty`s "too inclusive" design - if its a situation where `empty` doesn't do what is wanted, don't use it, in my opinion. I far prefer to build up from more fundamental calls, that have simpler semantics. You mention `is_numeric` - that seems the better starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!is_numeric()` instead `empty()`

thanks for such a important note, Rafa

Comment: **Note:**
To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use **is_numeric()**.
But thanks a lot! its work for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you state, 0 is considered empty.

The function you want is isset().

```
if (!isset($_POST['tmax'])) {
    $tmax = null;
} else {
    $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

Alternatively, remove the not operator and switch the code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for what are you trying to get.

```
if (!isset($_POST['tmax']) || $_POST['tmax'] == '') {
    $tmax = null;
}else {
    $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have placeholder - you can use this code:

```
<input type="number" name="tmax" max="99" min="-99" onclick="if (this.value == '') {this.value='0';} " placeholder="Temperatura max.">
```

don't forget add validation (before send form check on empty fileds )

and php to:

```
$tmax = 0;
if (isset($_POST['tmax'])) {
  $tmax = $_POST['tmax'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this solution is not esthetic for me, because the info is displayed on placeholder, and with 'value' the user can see the info.

Comment: Ok I change answer , now - with placeholder

Comment: This is a great technique if you *want* to replace an empty field with a default value. [To clarify for future readers: Original question wanted the opposite behavior - how to distinguish between an empty value, which means "not set", and is permitted in his code, and a value of zero.]